# Best practice для хранения загружаемых с сервера данных в Android-приложении

Tags: android, хранение-данных

Как правильнее всего хранить данные, которые загружаются с сервера и их хочется использовать в других activity этого приложения? 
Я понимаю, что прямой способ для этого - SQLite, но ведь тогда для каждого типа данных придётся придумывать промежуточное представление в БД и писать обёртки.
Единственный вариант, который мне приходит в голову - это сделать какой-либо класс Storage с применением паттерна singletone, объект этого класса будет как раз жить на протяжении всего жизненного цикла приложения, т.к. находится в static-памяти. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что в мобильной разработке так делать плохо, какие у этого способа есть подводные камни?

И ещё один связанный вопрос про хранение данных. Если пользователь получил с сервера при авторизации какой-нибудуь SID, понятно, что его можно хранить в Preferences, но как сделать, чтобы нельзя было забэкапить это приложение и восстановить на другом устройстве, получив доступ? Приходит в голову вариант с тем, чтобы шифровать его по какому-нибудь AndroidID, и при чтении расшифровывать обратно, тогда на другом устройстве в хорошем случае мы получим невалидный SID, насколько это плохой вариант?

Comment: Правила этого ресурса таковы, что в  вопросе может быть только одна проблема (один вопрос, без всяких даже связанных вопросов, тем более что прямой связи не наблюдается вовсе). Часть про шифрование задайте **новым вопросом**. Дело в том, что данный ресурс нацелен на переиспользование правильных решений, а не личную помощь и консультирование по проблемам автора. Другим людям, у которых будет проблема с сохранением данных с сервера, будет бесполезна часть про шифрование, а тем у кого проблемы с шифрованием не смогут найти решение.

Answer (score 2):

1. Если вы хотите хранить данные, полученные с сервера, после закрытия приложения, то вам нужно использовать SQLite. Да придется писать обертки. Можно использовать ORM, это уменьшит количество бойлерплейта. Storage в виде `Singleton` тоже имеет право на существование, но только в пределах одной сессии.
2. Лучше такие данные шифровать. Пока на сколько мне известно это единственный вариант. Может кто-нибудь еще знает как от этого можно защитить приложение. Буду рад узнать.

Comment: По первому вопросу. Да, хочется как раз хранить данные для одной сессии, я имею ввиду то, что мне этот вариант (с синглтоном) кажется каким-то надуманным и является "хаком" жизненных циклов. Кто-нибудь вообще пользуется таким вариантом в реальных проектах?

Comment: ну это не очень практично. т.к. можно словить outofmemory. Нужно самому очищать данные, которые не нужны.